# Correct pattern to use for a function unmarshaling into a struct?

Tags: go

I have a function, `callAPI`, with a return-type `interface{}`.

I have a struct, `Company`, in which I want to `Unmarshal()` the resulting JSON from `callAPI()`.

Should I instead have `callAPI()` return a `Company{}`?

Or, should I have `callAPI()` return `[]byte`, and then `Unmarshal()` into a `Company`?

Or, is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I clearly think that returning an `interface{}` is the worst API, it's very unclear about how it works.
Returning a `byte[]`, `string` or `io.Reader` is clearer to me as I understand that as a consumer (someone who use the API), I'll need to parse it.

But I belive that when you can, just return an object, however this depends, if your object is very specific (not very general) having an external API using it might be worst for clarity. (thoses kinds of objects are the ugly one you hide as private so other modules wont attempt to use them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a pointer to the target value as an argument.  Pass the pointer value through to json.Unmarshal:

```
func callAPI(a1 T1, a2 T2, v interface{}) error {
    // use a1, a2, ... to get API response []byte, p
    return json.Unmarshal(p, v)
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var c Company
err := callAPI(a1, a2, &c)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
// Use company.
```

Replace the placeholders `a1`, `a2`, `T1` and `T2` with whatever arguments are appropriate for your function.

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wcs3qXVQG2H).

Comment: In this case, would my Company be type Company *struct { ... }?

Comment: Use  `type Company struct { <insert fields here>  }`

Comment: How is the pointer `p` involved?  Normally I would `json.Unmarshsal(body, v)`, where `body` is the response body, no?

Comment: See  https://play.golang.org/p/wcs3qXVQG2H.  The variable `c` is a `Company`.  The value of the expression `&c` is a `*Company`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my confusion!